# Proof sequence by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, solution-verification

I have the following problem I am not sure about.
Let n = 0, 1, 2, ... and show that the equation $a_0 = 1, a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} + 1$

has the solution $ a_n = 2^n - 1$

Base case: $ n = 0 \\ a_0 = 2^0 - 1 = 0$

Now what exactly do I proof? I tried doing something like this but $2^n - 1 = 2a_{n} + 1$ but I cannot make it equal.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't meant to be $a_1 = 1$ and $a_0=0$ instead?

Comment: No, just checked the paper exactly as in the thread.

Comment: Then your paper has a typo in it or it was a trick question.  You showed that $2^0-1=0\neq 1=a_0$ so the base case fails since the proposed formula for $a_n$ which was $2^n-1$ doesn't hold for $a_0$.  The proposed formula does work however for if $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$ instead... Alternatively, rather than changing the base cases, you could keep $a_0=0$ and instead change $a_n = 2^{n\color{red}{+1}}-1$ to fix the problem to an actually true statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

Observe that $$a_{n+1}+1=2(a_n+1)$$

$$=\cdots=2^{n-r}(a_r+1)$$ where $n\ge r\ge0$

By induction if $a_n=2^n-1,$

$$a_{n+1}+1=2(2^n)$$

Comment: My final solution is 4^n - 1 = 4^n -1. Is that right?

Comment: I expanded wrong now I have the correct solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a_n = 2^n-1$. Then show that $a_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} - 1$ based on that premise. Alongside the base case, that completes the induction proof.

---

**Hint:**

Notice that $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1$ per the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

By induction, if $a_{n + 1} = 2a_n + 1$ has the solution $a_n=2^n - 1$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$, then is must also hold for $n + 1$ so that $a_{n + 1} = 2^{n + 1} - 1$.

We can insert the hypothesis ($a_n=2^n - 1$) into the recurrence with the inductive value $n$

$a_{n+1} = 2a_n+1=2(2^n - 1) + 1 = 2 * 2^n - 2 + 1 = 2 * 2^n - 1 = 2^{n + 1} - 1$.

Comment: You have a lot of mistakes surrounding when to write $n$, when to write $n+1$ and when to write $(n+1)+1$ or $n+2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you please point to where you find these mistakes?

Comment: For instance, in the first line you say $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$ and in the second line you say that $a_{n+1}=2a_{n+1}+1$... the LHS of each are $a_{n+1}$ when in the second it should have been $a_{n+2}$ or $a_{(n+1)+1}$ depending on how you prefer to write it

Comment: @JMoravitz I have made it more clear now.